# Unable to use lato font

Tags: fonts, texlive, texlive-2017

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

When compiled with xelatex, it produces the following document:

[image: Compiled document]

Quite clearly, it is not a lato font.

FWIW, here are the relevant lines (at least, I think so :) ) from the logfile:

```
(/home/user/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lato/lato.sty
Package: lato 2011/08/06 Lato

(/home/user/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/slantsc/slantsc.sty
Package: slantsc 2012/01/01 v2.11 Provide Slanted an Italic Small Caps

(/home/user/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 35.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 45.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 55.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 65.
)) (/tmp/1.aux)
\openout1 = `1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TU+fla on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file TUfla.fd. on input line 3.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/fla/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 3.

[1

] (/tmp/1.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

What is happening here? Why is it substituting fonts when Lato is available? Has it something to do with font encodings? I dread that word! Or something about T1, OTF, TTF, etc. I do not understand these, either. Or sffamily, etc.? How do I correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package is not meant for xelatex. But you can load the font like this in xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lato}

\begin{document}
Grüße an die Welt
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. And since it does not work as suggested by Andreas, will you please point me to some source that explains what is all this xelatex, T1, fontenc, etc. about?

Comment: Well as I'm doing fonts in latex for more than 20 years, my source is mostly in my head. I simply know how it works ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Right, it's about fontencoding and T1. :-) That should work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

Comment: T1-encoding is not suitable for xelatex. Try instead Hello World "Grüße an die Welt" and you will see why.